# segmentation fault checking user arguments c

Tags: c

I am trying to validate user input from the command line with argc and argv but am running into a segmentation fault and am not sure why.

I want to validate the user has entered a positive int (so argc =2 and argv is positive).

Here is my code:

```
int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (argc != 2 && k <1)
    {
          return 1;
    }
}
```

The k < 1 part of my code seems to be working fine, but I get segmentation errors every time I try to run without the program name and an argument (agrc !=2).

EDIT:

More clear description of the error handling problem:

If I run ./myprogram -2
then I get my return 1 as expected.

If I run ./myprogram hjdksfhdsk
then I get my return 1 as expected.

If I run ./myprogram 
then I get a segmentation fault.

It is this behaviour that makes me think my handling of the argc value is at fault, but I am not sure why I cannot just test argc !=2.

Comment: shall be `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: The second argument to main is const char*: not string.  string is not a basic type in C.  You also have a logic error - if there are no arguments, the atoi will fail.  Does this even compile?

Comment: Thanks guys, Edited to char *argv[] but I am still getting the segmentation fault.  I think the issue seems to be related to my handing of argc and not the string argv.

Comment: I assume there is a line like `typedef char *string;` somewhere since the OP is facing a run time error, not a compile time error.

Comment: @cup it's not `const char*`. It can be rewrite.

Comment: _why I cannot just test argc !=2._ It is too late is to test.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY @ Basile Thanks  - fixed now.  I was trying to be too clever!

Comment: BTW, program arguments are not user input. The input has been made to the shell. The shell is parsing the command line. Then it starts your program (after expanding the command). Your program may read afterwards some input from `stdin` (e.g. using `scanf`)

Comment: Thanks for that. It was my loose language when I talked about user input. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is incorrect, since in *C* `string` is not a built-in type (and is not a standard type defined in some standard header - notice that *C++* has [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) defined in its `<string>` standard header).

The signature of `main` has to be

```
int main(int argc, char**argv);
```

The convention is that `argv[argc]` is the null pointer, and the `argc` pointers from `argv[0]` to `argv[argc-1]` are non-null pointers to null-terminated strings.

<sup>Notice that (at least on Linux and Posix systems) program arguments are not user input to the program. The shell has been given a command line as input and has expanded that command line into program arguments. Your program could later read some input, e.g. with `scanf`.</sup>

You cannot convert a `NULL` pointer with `atoi`, so you should check `argc` before doing the conversion.

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   if (argc!=2) { 
      fprintf(stderr, "%s needs two arguments\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   };
   int k = atoi(argv[1]);
   if (k<=0) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "%s wants a positive first argument, but got %s\n",
              argv[1]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   // now do the real thing
 }
```

BTW, I believe that (at least on Linux or Posix system) a program should accept the `--help` argument per the [GNU coding standard](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces). I suggest you to use [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) (notably `getopt_long`) or [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp) to parse program arguments.

At last, compile with all warnings and debug information (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`) and [learn](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Answer (score 3):

Your main should be

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
```

And do the check before using on `atoi` on `argv[1]`

Also all paths should return a value. Bung `return 0;` at the end

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted string is not a base type.  However since you are getting results in one case your segmentation fault has to do with the atoi on argv 1.  In c arrays are 0 based so you're trying to convert uninitialized memory.  Use the argc test before the atoi.